# Is there a way to have multiple values in one if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

Can't believe I'm resorting to going on Stack Overflow to ask this rather than Google it, but is there a way to have multiple values in one if statement? For example, rather than using:

```
if ($var == 'value' || $var == 'othervalue') : 
    return true;
endif;
```

...you could do something along the lines of:

```
if ($var == ('value' || 'othervalue')) : 
    return true;
endif;
```

I know it's probably a very basic yes/no answer, but it's just something I've wanted to know but never really had the time to look up.

Comment: You've "Never really had the time to look up", but expect us to make time to answer for you

Comment: not sure i understand what you need, but is this showing you what you wanted to know ? http://codepad.org/0eIyMMVg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if (in_array('needle', array('value1', 'value2', 'needle'))){

}
```

Comment: I thought of that, but I'm looking for something that will let the intial value ($var) be equal to either of the two values ('value' or 'othervalue').

Comment: @Matt That is exactly what `in_array()` will do. If the value is equal to any one of the values in the array, it will match.

Comment: What do you mean by matching either two values? if in_array finds at least one match it will return true. if you mean matching both values, variable can't have two different values at the same time so matching both values is impossible.

Comment: Ah, figured it. Great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no short syntax, but you can always simulate it if you want to. I.e., something like:

```
if (in_array($var, array('value', 'othervalue')) : 
    return true;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for this:

```
$arr = array('value', 'othervalue');
if (in_array($var, $arr))
   return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `array` and then use `in_array()` to check if `$var` is present. Something on the lines -

```
$my_array = array('value', 'othervalue');

if ( in_array($var, $my_array) )
    return true;
```